# Добавление элементов в существующий элемент NAVIGATOR

Tags: lsfusion

В формах через DESIGN я могу добавлять компоненты, можно ли как-то добавлять элементы в созданный ранее элемент навигатора? Пример создания элемента:

```
NAVIGATOR {
    NEW FOLDER catalogs 'Классификаторы' FIRST WINDOW toolbar {
        NEW FOLDER cat1 'Справочники' {
            NEW periodForm;
        //    NEW scenarioList;
        }
    ....
```

И как-то так добавить элемент в него позже

```
NAVIGATOR {
    FOLDER cat1 {
        NEW scenarioList;
    }
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменить существующий элемент навигатора можно с помощью [инструкции редактирования](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/NAVIGATOR_statement/#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). В ней не нужно указывать ключевое слово `FOLDER`, только имя элемента навигатора. Корректный код будет выглядеть вот так:

```
NAVIGATOR {
    cat1 {
        NEW scenarioList;
    }
....
```

При вставке дочернего элемента сам элемент с именем `cat1` должен являться элементом типа папка (созданным с помощью `NEW FOLDER`).